# Set margin 0 on all Material UI v5 <h*> tags with MuiCssBaseline

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking for a way to extend MUI v5's MuiCssBaseline with a rule to set `margin: 0` on  all the heading and paragraph tags. I've tried this:

```
MuiCssBaseline: {
  styleOverrides: {
    '@global': {
      h4 {
        margin: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it resulted in `TS18004: No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'h4'. Either declare one or provide an initializer`.

What's the right way? Should it be set in `MuiCssBaseline` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example of one syntax for how to handle this in the theme. You can find documentation about overriding global styles here: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#4-global-css-override.

```
import * as React from "react";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: `
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
          margin: 0;
        }
      `
    }
  }
});

export default function OverrideCssBaseline() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <h1>h1 element</h1>
      <h2>h2 element</h2>
      <h3>h3 element</h3>
      <h4>h4 element</h4>
      <h5>h5 element</h5>
      <h6>h6 element</h6>
      <p>p element</p>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit global styles]

Another approach that is not reliant on `CssBaseline` is to use the `GlobalStyles` component as show below.

```
import * as React from "react";
import GlobalStyles from "@mui/material/GlobalStyles";

export default function GlobalStylesExample() {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyles styles={{ "h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p": { margin: 0 } }} />
      <h1>h1 element</h1>
      <h2>h2 element</h2>
      <h3>h3 element</h3>
      <h4>h4 element</h4>
      <h5>h5 element</h5>
      <h6>h6 element</h6>
      <p>p element</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit global styles]

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the accepted answer this is what I came up with.

```
MuiCssBaseline: {
  styleOverrides: {
    'some-prop': {
      ...
    },
    'p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6': {
      margin: 0
    }
  }
}
```