# How can I make theme styles in Material UI override a page-level font inherit CSS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm writing a browser extension using React+MUI, which will get injected into the DOM of a page. That page contains a CSS file with a rule that does the following:

```
h6 {
  font: inherit;
}
```

When I put a `<h6>` element in my extension's DOM, it is not bolded, even though I'm explicitly setting a font weight using a Material UI theme:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    h6: {
      fontWeight: 800
    }       
  },        
});
```

Here's a working example showing the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-waterfall-5u2q7o?file=/src/App.js

What's the best way for getting the rules in the theme to have precedence over page-level CSS rules that bleed into my widget's DOM?

Answer (score 2):

The theme styles don't have any global impact on `h6` tags. You need to explicitly use the `Typography` component in order for those theme styles to have an impact.

Here's a modified version of your code:

```
import "./styles.css";

import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

export const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    h6: {
      fontWeight: 800
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="App">
        <Typography variant="h6">This should be bold</Typography>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit theme Typography styles]

Comment: That solution works for me, although it's much more verbose than using common HTML tags like `<h6>`. Is there another Material approach *besides* a theme that I could look at that will allow me to specify more specific styles, or should I look at adding CSS files to my React code and having more specific rules there?

Comment: There are various ways to do global styles (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76082686/set-margin-0-on-all-material-ui-v5-h-tags-with-muicssbaseline/76087950#76087950) using Material-UI, but there's also nothing wrong with doing the styles in CSS files.